# How it is possiblle to flush to disk a transaction programmatically using Xodus?

Tags: xodus, nosql

I m trying to flush to disk a transaction without to set in the configuration durable write.

It is possible to command to flush just for a specific transaction?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of the [Environments API](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Environments), it is not possible to configure particular transaction to be durable.

There is a work around: you can manually invoke the `EnvironmentImpl#flushAndSync()` method after a transaction is flushed or committed. The method flushes not flushed data and forces OS to sync modified files and directory structure to storage device. Though, there can be a race when another transaction can be executed in parallel after your transaction, which you'd like to be durable, is flushed/committed and before the `EnvironmentImpl#flushAndSync()` method is invoked. To solve the race, you can use commit hook. For given `Transaction txn` and `EnvironmentImpl env`, define the following commit hook:

```
txn.setCommitHook(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        env.flushAndSync();
    }
});
```

Probably, it makes sense to expose the `EnvironmentImpl#flushAndSync()` method to the API.